# replace not working with regex

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to replace a string input by a user. I have the following input (as a firstname, lastname)...

```
John, Doe
```

I am use the following code:

```
$userInput = $userInput -replace '\s',''
$firstName = $userInput -replace ",*$",""
$lastName = $userInput -replace "^*,",""
```

Output looks like the following:

```
$userInput = John,Doe
$firstName = John,Doe
$lastName = JohnDoe
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
$userInput = John,Doe
$firstName = John
$lastName = Doe
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$firstName, $lastName = $userInput -split ',\s*'`

Comment: @FiddleFreak I've included that in my answer since I was writing something similar, but of course if PetSerAl writes an answer feel free to accept that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`,*$` says to find 0 or more commas at the very end of the string (not what you want).

`^*,` is.. well, I'm not really sure it would be considered valid regex. I guess it would mean find 0 or more "beginning of string" followed by a comma (it's a weird thing to specify).

So for first name, you would really want something like this:

```
$firstName = $userInput -replace ',.*$',''
```

So that says, find a comma followed by 0 or more of any character followed by the end of the string (then replace it with nothing).

For last name:

```
$lastName = $userInput -replace '^.*?,',''
```

And this says, find the beginning of the string, followed by 0 or more of any character (non-greedy, that's what the `?` after the `*` means), then replace it with nothing.

Aaaand as I'm writing this, @PetSerAl commented what my last solution was going to be, which is to use a split:

```
$firstName, $lastName = $userInput -split ',\s*'
```